# I'm a super admin and I want to give an admin the ability to add new users...?

Tags: admin, users

How can I do that? So far the admin can only add exisiting users.

Comment: The admin role should already have the ability to add new users, are you working in a multisite setup or something else?

Comment: yes its a multisite setup. its for a group of university of iowa blogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up to xLRDxREVENGEx's answer, here's a screenshot of the checkbox you need to check in the network admin section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for some reason i could not take a screenshot at all

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx: no problem. I use the chrome extension called AwesomeScreenshot to take those ( http://jbl.me/4c ). Really useful.

Answer (score 1):

you need to visit this page http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/network/settings.php and about halfway down in the Registration Settings area fine this "Add New Users" and make sure it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

According to the N[etwork Admin section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Users_Screen) of WordPress (which is also what the "super admin is". You need to add the user first, and then specify which site within the network they will be a part of. I assume you can assign the role within that network at that time.